# Is it possible to programmatically detect a click on the mac desktop?

Tags: macos, applescript, desktop

I want to whip something up that would run a small script every time i clicked on the Desktop. Any hints on how to make this happen?

For those interested, the script would toggle the display of desktop icons.

Comment: Using just applescript, no you can not. (KenThomases' suggestion is probably not want you're needing.) I would suggest you make a script applet to keep in the dock or script menu that toggles it. Or a script you give a global key shortcut to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean on the desktop background, not any icon. You could create a transparent overlay window, use `[window setIgnoresMouseEvents:NO]` to make it receive clicks, and set its window level to something between the desktop and the icons (`kCGDesktopWindowLevel` and `kCGDesktopIconWindowLevel`).

You would presumably want to create one of those per screen and monitor for changes in the screen configuration to add, remove, or resize them as appropriate. Either observe the `NSApplicationDidChangeScreenParametersNotification` or implement the `-applicationDidChangeScreenParameters:` application delegate method (which amounts to the same thing).